# Xcode 11 can't see app icon's pack of iMessages extension after update

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, imessage-extension

I can no longer set iMessages app icon type file to the extension app in the target->general->App icons->App icons source.

[It can't see iMessages app icons pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CybOQ.png)
[But I have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXBPI.jpg)
It's like searching not for "iMessage app icons" but "app icons pack" of main application.
Well it's accepting main application app icons type file in Target and I though that iMessages apps no longer needs the other types of resolutions but When I'm trying to upload to the App Store it gives me following errors.
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWsBN.png)

The iMessages application clearly needs the iMessages app icons type resolution images but it does not let me too choose one.
I had not issue till the update.

I'm stuck on this days. Can anyone help me.

Comment: xcode 15, iOS 17 not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, click `Stickers.xcassets` change the `iMessage App Icon`'s name to `AppIcon`.

Comment: Worked for me. Every other solution I saw was related to image sizes being off. After upgrading an app from 10.4 to 13.1, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. I saw the red App Icon Source in the general tab, clicked on this, and only the app icon set from the main bundle is available...

Then the project doesn't compile anymore.

I tried to add the CFBundleIconName to the iMessage extension plist, but this is not taken into account and the project still doesn't compile.

My solution was to restore the project from a Time Machine backup, right before I clicked on the App Icon Source setting. It still shows in red, but at least it does compile.

Comment: Yeah my solution was same too, But it's kinda good luck. One missclick and you have to rewind progress. If I knew where is the file where the path is defined, problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug xCode
The following helped me:
- In Project navigator select you project
- Press Menu->View->Show Code review
- In view local revision find a fragment that looks something like this:

**!!! Please note - there are two such fragments - for debug and for release**

```
buildSettings = {
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = "AppIcon";
                CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
                DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 12345678;
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "MesTest MessagesExtension/Info.plist";
```

and correct the value of the key ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = "AppIcon" with you real name equal is Assets. In my case it is "iMessage App Icon"

[Were find Real "iMessage App Icon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1jVk.png)

At the same time, in the project editor this choice will be red, but ignore it, the main thing is that everything will work and be generated as it should

[ignore this red text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DSxW.png)

Answer (score -1):

Somehow the accepted answer did not work for me. What worked was:

1. In project settings select the target corresponding to your extension
2. Switch to **Build Settings** tab
3. Search for **Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name** and change it to whatever name is right for you (mine was 'Messages Icon')

Edit : 
And then I tried again just to check and the accepted answer **did** work.